# node / formidable - problem with documentation - how to save files to dir?

Tags: node.js, formidable

I 'am a newbie programmer.
Today I want to install and configuration formidable for my project.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable
I have question:

- where I find information about how to save files to dir? I see on npmjs example code with express.js, but in this code not include information about save, documentation also not included information about save files to dir.

How I should read that documentation like this? I will be grateful for any comments, probably at the moment I don't think like programmer.

Answer (score -1):

The documentation says that files will be saved ...

You should try the examples before making random guesses.